# Return count for characters in the comment and perform action based on the length

Tags: comments, conditional-content, php

I am calling recent comments into my template with

```
$comment->post_title
```

the variable length is specified like this :

```
SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,180)
```

how could I write a conditional statement just for comments that exceed the limits of the vairable >180 ?

I was thinking It would be good to have a ... for longer comments and a more link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a function to perform that:

```
recent_comment_text_more($comment_content)
```

that function would look like (in case you're using PHP, part of your code looks from another language):

```
function recent_comment_text_more($comment_content, $more_href)  {
    if (strlen($comment_content) > 180) {
        $comment_content = substr($comment_content, 0, 177) . sprintf('<a href="%s">... (more)</a>', $more_href);
    } 
    return $comment_content;
}
```

Good luck!

## Multibyte charset safe variant

As pointed out in a comment, e.g. for UTF-8, see [mb_internal_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) for specifying the encoding to use:

```
function recent_comment_text_more($comment_content, $more_href)  {
    if (mb_strlen($comment_content) > 180) {
        $comment_content = mb_substr($comment_content, 0, 177) . sprintf('<a href="%s">... (more)</a>', $more_href);
    } 
    return $comment_content;
}
```

Comment: Use `mb_substr()` or multibyte characters may break.

Comment: I added a quick edit; the shortened content was being stored in `$comment_conent`, which would have resulted in this not working correctly.